# What would happen if an electrical current was passed through a black hole?

Tags: electromagnetism, black-holes, electric-current, electrical-resistance, event-horizon

Can black holes conduct electricity? And if so, how effectively?

Comment: Conducting electricity involves attaching electrodes, running the current, and measuring the outcomes. None of this is possible. A black hole is not an object, but a region of spacetime where time stops and the speed of light and electricity becomes zero. Your question may be based on wrong assumptions of what a black hole is and makes no sense the way it is phrased.

Answer (score 6):

Kip Thorne has said the event horizon (as a "membrane") possesses an electrical impedance of 377 ohms. I do not know how much is resistive and how much is reactive.

Comment: Cool answer. For references, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Membrane_paradigm .  According to Thorne, "It is fruitful to conceive of the black hole as an electrically conducting, spheroidal membrane".